# How to find the inverse of following matrix in $\mathbb Z/7 \mathbb Z$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, finite-fields, congruences

How to find the inverse of following matrix in  $\mathbb Z/7 \mathbb Z$?

$$A= \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc}
      1&2&0\\
      0&3&-1\\-2&0&2
    \end{array}
\right] $$

Need some hint-

Comment: Do the usual inverse matrix method, but do all operations mod $7$. Thus, augment the given matrix with the identity matrix and row reduce, mod $7$ at each step (Note: fractions use inverses mod $7$, not division).

Comment: Find the normal $A^{-1}$ and then take the entires modulo $7$

Comment: see here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MatrixInverse.html

Comment: I got $$A^{-1}_{\mod 7}=\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
 2 & 1 & 4 \\
 3 & 3 & 5 \\
 2 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
I used *Mathematica* command `Inverse[{{1, 2, 0}, {0, 3, -1}, {-2, 0, 2}}, Modulus -> 7]` @Dr.SonnhardGraubner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the details of the computation:
    \begin{align*}
   &\begin{bmatrix}
     \begin{array}{@{}ccc|ccc@{}}
1 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 3 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\-2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
    \end{bmatrix} \xrightarrow[R_2\leftarrow -2R_2]{R_3\leftarrow R_3 + 2R_1}
    \begin{bmatrix}
    \begin{array}{@{}ccc|ccc@{}}
1 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & -2 & 0\\0 & 4 & 2 & 2 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
    \end{bmatrix}\\[1ex]&\xrightarrow{R_3\leftarrow R_3 + 3R_2}
    \begin{bmatrix}
    \begin{array}{@{}ccc|ccc@{}}
1 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & -2 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 1
\end{array}
    \end{bmatrix}\xrightarrow{R_2\leftarrow R_2 - 2R_3}\\[1ex]
    &
    \begin{bmatrix}
    \begin{array}{@{}ccc|ccc@{}}
1 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0 & 3 &3 & -2 \\0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 1
\end{array}
    \end{bmatrix}
    \xrightarrow{R_1\leftarrow R_1 - 2R_2}
    \begin{bmatrix}
    \begin{array}{@{}ccc|ccc@{}}
1 & 0 & 0 & \color{red}2 & \color{red}1 & \color{red}{-3}\\0 & 1 & 0 & \color{red}3 &\color{red}3 & \color{red}{-2} \\0 & 0 & 1 & \color{red}2 & \color{red}1 & \color{red}1
\end{array}
    \end{bmatrix} 
\end{align*}